# WHy is my FIX session Starting and Ending UTC insted of Local?

Tags: quickfix, quickfixn

I am using quickfix .net engine.

```
StartTime=17:40:00
EndTime=17:25:00
```

I am running this on a New York server and clock on desktop shows NY local time.

However, the FIX session starts and ends at UTC time. My understanding of fix config was that the times were always Local.

Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to read the [config section](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html) properly, once more.

> StartTime, EndTime - time in the format of HH:MM:SS, time is represented in UTC

To use local time in the FIX config, you need to set in the config

> UseLocalTime=Y

It is N by default. But an important point

> Times in messages will still be set to UTC as this is required by the FIX specifications.